# How do I install curtain rod mounts correctly if I keep hitting metal?

Tags: mounting, curtain-rail

I am installing Double Bay Window Mounts. If I have measured the correct height, 84", and the recommended width of 3" from the window on both sides why am I hitting  metal when I drill the holes? I'm using the supplied 1 1/2" screws and anchors. What can I do?

Comment: Is it possible there's electrical running through that wall?  You might be hitting metal plates on top of the studs that are there to protect the wire.  See this question for an example of that: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101066/why-did-my-electrician-put-metal-plates-wherever-the-stud-is-drilled-through

Comment: I am hitting metal 4" above and 3" on both sides of every window in the Bay Window. I don't believe it's protecting any wiring. It seems it might be the metal used to frame a window. Thank you Nate.